# Missing Cookies; getting 1/3.. I thought this was handled automatically, why are things not working correctly

Tags: c#, cookies

There is this trend of cookies not turning up.  I copy fiddler exactly and it should be a simple task since it's handled automatically anyway.  Why am I not getting proper cookie retrieval?

```
public class HTTP : WebClient
{
    public HTTP()
        : this(new CookieContainer())
    { }

    public HTTP(CookieContainer c)
    {
        CookieContainer = c;
    }
    public CookieContainer CookieContainer { get; set; }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address);

        var castRequest = request as HttpWebRequest;
        if (castRequest != null)
        {
            castRequest.CookieContainer = CookieContainer;
            castRequest.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
            castRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/25.0.1364.172 Safari/537.22";

        }

        return request;
    }
} 


public void checkUrl()
{
CookieContainer cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
HTTP client = new HTTP(cookieJar);

string responseData = client.DownloadString(url);
       responseData = client.UploadString(url, loginData);
rtb.Text = responseData;
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate, at which moment cookies are lost? Do you check CookieContainer after DownloadString? Do you expect cookies from previous call to checkUrl to persist in next call?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to hook into the WebResponse and read the cookies from there. The request does not change after it is sent.